# remove particular namespace via XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to remove particular namespace for my xml using XSLT.

for example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root xmlns="http://test.com" xmlns:ns2="http://test2.com">
  <ns2:element1>hello</ns2:element1>
  <ns2:element2>hello</ns2:element2>
</root>
```

How to come up the XSLT to remove http://test.com namespace?

Thanks

Comment: Are you aware that removing the namespace declaration will change the semantics of your file? As it is, `root` is in the `http://test.com` namespace, because that is the default namespace at that point. When you remove `xmlns="http://test.com"`, `root` will no longer in that namespace, and this will affect schema validation and XSLT name matching for that element.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
<xsl:template match="ns2:*">
    <xsl:element name="local-name()">
        <xsl:copy-of select="*">
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: It's better to use `<apply-templates>`.